# Update sqlite database with multiple columns

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I want update database with checking 2 columns. If both columns are same then update, else insert as new row.

```
        mydatabase.insertOrThrow(DATABASE_TABLE, null, records);
        } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
            String where = KEY_ADDRESS +"=? and " + KEY_VALUE + "=?";
            String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(address), String.valueOf(value)};
            mydatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, records, where,whereArgs);
        }
```

Adress and value are primary key, address is unique.

Now it only insert at beginning. When i change value it doesn't insert any record.

This is my create function:

```
        String create = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s ( %s TEXT ,%s TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE ,"
+" %s INTEGER, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(%s, %s) );",
 DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_VALUE, KEY_ARRAY,
     KEY_TİME, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_VALUE);
```

I think problem is in insert function. It insert at beginning with value but after i change the value it doesn't insert as new row. It update rows when i change back to old value.

Sorry for adding new information about question but i can't ask new question.

Comment: I solved problem. I wrote unique in create statement.

Answer (score 3):

```
public SQLiteDatabase db;

 db = openOrCreateDatabase("databasename.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
 String see = "create table if not exists tablename(id integer primary key autoincrement,address varchar(120) not null,address varchar(20) primary key, value varchar(20)unique)";
  db.execSQL(see);

  String selectQuery="select * from tablename";
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String address =cursor.getString(1);
            String value=cursor.getString(2);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

String address1=String.valueOf(address);
String value1=String.valueOf(value)

if(address.equal(address1) && value.equal(value1))
{
try
{
db.insertOrThrow(DATABASE_TABLE, null, records);
   } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
        String where = KEY_ADDRESS +"=? and " + KEY_VALUE + "=?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(address), String.valueOf(value)};
        db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, records, where,whereArgs);
    }
 }
```

Use this code.

Comment: Are you adding new column "reference"? This code didn't work. It says cannot resolve method openOrCreateDatabase. I also have more columns. They only keep records.I used address column instead of reference but it gives nullpointerexception in if statement.

Comment: I was used reference column. U can replace that column. Its easy way of database access. For more reference use this link.    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29

Comment: You do assignments in while with cursor. Do not they just keep the last values?